# How to display hide text in acrobat?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I want to create one pdf file. and I that pdf contain questions. I want to add one button or image so that whenever user click on that image so I will show the answer below question. I means I don't want user open pdf file and see the answer but if they want to see answer so they can click on button or image file. how to do this using adobe acrobat? thank in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is essentially layers on Adobe Acrobat.

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-layers.html

What you want to do is create the answers as individually separate layers as described in the link above.

Once you have a separate layer [*answer*], you can associate a link to show/hide it - *The link in this case will be what someone clicks to show the answer.*

http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-layers.html#add_layer_navigation

Repeat the above for each question/answer pair.

Comment: Can I add text and make that text as layer?

Comment: Yes. It will be treated as a block which can be manipulated like a layer.

Answer (score 1):

Layers are a simple way to show/hide all answers at once.

If you want to show/hide individual answers, you could put them into a text field set to readonly, and show/hide this field on an individual (or global) basis.